# Convert image to a Chromaticity image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to write a program that takes an image and converts it to a [chromaticity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromaticity) image in MATLAB.

As I understand it, to achieve chromaticity, you must calculate `r,g,b` from `R,G,B`, by:

[image: equations]

So, I've done this (or at least attempted it) but it just returns a black image...

Here's my program:

```
    img = double(imread('ref_images/foliage.jpg'));
    %temp
    chrom_Img = zeros(size(img, 1), size(img, 2));

    %split channels
    R_ = img(:,:,1);
    G_ = img(:,:,2);
    B_ = img(:,:,3);

    %sum RGB channels (R+G+B)
    s_RGB = R_ + G_ + B_;

    %calc r g b with r = R/sum etc
    r_ = R_./s_RGB;
    g_ = G_./s_RGB;
    b_ = B_./s_RGB;

    %assign to chrom_Img
    %chrom_Img = cat(3, r_, g_, b_); %also tried this
    chrom_Img(:,:,1) = r_;
    chrom_Img(:,:,2) = g_;
    chrom_Img(:,:,3) = b_;
```

What am I missing or implementing incorrect for this to be happening?

To see an example image, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rg_chromaticity#Illustration).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is data type.  When dealing with integers any fraction less than one is zero:

```
>> uint8(10)/uint8(100)
ans =
    0
```

When you do `r_ = R_./s_RGB;` everything goes to zero.

Also, instead of the manual sum (`s_RGB = R_ + G_ + B_;`), you can do:

```
s_RGB = sum(double(img),3);
```

This will sum over the third dimension.

Convert `img` to double up front and it should work fine:

```
chrom_Img = bsxfun(@rdivide,double(img),sum(double(img),3));
```

Result (based on [this image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Elkhorn_Slough.jpg)):

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for posting. Great answer. I'm glad it was something simple. Thanks again :D